# How to save associated model objects on the creation time of the parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to save associated model class instances (I use an `has_many :through => ...` association) on the creation time of the parent model. That is, I have the `Article`, `Category` and `ArticleCategoryRelationship` classes: when I create a new article I would like to make it possible to use check boxes in order to choose related categories (these categories already exist in database) and on the creation\saving time to create a new article-category relationship for each checked\selected check box.

The problem seams to be related to the fact that when I save the article object it is not created yet and so I can not "automatically" add article-category relationships. That is, since in the `ArticleCategoryRelationship` has `article_is` and `category_id` attributes, the `article_id` attribute is not "automatically" populated with the `article.id` value.

**How can I handle the above situation in order to create article-category relationships** (maybe taking advantage from the Ruby on Rails association model system)**?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use accepts_nested_attributes_for. Take a look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).